# What is the best way to convert a CVS project with many modules into one git repository?

Tags: git, version-control, cvs

I've inherited an old CVS project consisting of many modules. This split into modules is mainly historical, logically they belong together.
I want to switch it to a GIT project. git cvsimport seems to be restricted to conversion of one module, but I do not want to use GIT submodules for the CVS modules - too much overhead.

I've looked into cvs2git briefly - it seems to work, but it creates many spurious commits for the tags (OK, some of the CVS tags do not cover the whole CVS source tree).

Another tool I've heard of is tailor - but I could not get it to work at all.

Any other recommendations?

Comment: I'm hitting this issue also. Did you ever figure out anything?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your best chance is to declare a root module in your `CVSROOT/modules` and reference all other modules under it:

```
#M  everything  Composite module which holds all other submodules
everything  &foo \
        &bar \
        &baz
```

– and then invoke `git-cvsimport` as usual:

```
git cvsimport -k -A authors everything -C my-git-repo
```

This approach doesn't always work for me, though (I'm getting the known error message `WARNING: file foo doesn't match strip_path bar ignoring`). Here's what Jeff King [suggests](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/cvsimport-error-when-modulename-is-td4565923.html):

> As a hack, if you can move files in the CVS repository (and if you
>   can't, try using cvssuck or similar to pull them locally, and then do
>   the import from there), then move everything to a submodule "foo", and
>   import that module.
>
> Alternatively, you might check out some of the alternative importers
>   like parsecvs or cvs2git. I don't know if they would handle this
>   situation better.
>
> And as a super-hacky alternative, you could import each module
>   separately and then stich them all together using git-filter-branch.

Since `git-cvsimport` seems to be the only utility that supports author mapping,
I suggest you move the files within your repository and then import a single module using `git-cvsimport`.

Comment: cvs2git also has some kind of author mapping - I used it to map the CVS author names to the new GIT names.

Comment: In the old project I'm working on, the sticky spot seems to be "modules within a module".   hacking up the CVSROOT to simply put all the files in one directory where they belong, as quoted above, seemed to be the fastest way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I proceeded with just straight cvs2git calls. I selected the CVS modules to keep, and let the beast run for about 1 day.

Afterwards I used git filter-branch to merge committer information from CVS with those from GIT - this actually did not run through completely, I overlooked some names, but as this is more an aesthetic question, I let it stay.

In order to stitch together the histories between the old CVS repo and the new GIT repo, I used grafts to stitch together the histories, and then (after creating the graft file), I ran git filter-branch again to fuse the histories together.

This fusion was not fully successful (there is some overlap left), but it is good enough to follow the history.